# How to delete custom variable of google analytics

Tags: php, google-analytics, drupal-6

For testing purpose, mistakenly I created unwanted custom variable. Now I want to delete those variable.
Is there any way to delete those variable?

I had created those variables using the following script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   pageTracker._setCustomVar(1,"Author","Xyz abc",3);
   pageTracker._setCustomVar(1,"author","Nimbus",3);
</script>
```

I want to delete both the variables.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
 _gaq.push(['_deleteCustomVar', 1]);
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration#_gat.GA_Tracker_._deleteCustomVar